# HTML to run javascript even when page is closed

Tags: javascript, php, html, offline

Okay, this is a problem I have been having for sometime now, and I cant find a solution, Anywhere!

**My Problem:**

My HTML content is available as web application that can be used offline, but I want the contact form to also be available offline.

Is there anyway the user can fill in the contact form when they have no connection and then for a script to run that holds that inputted data until a connection is established.

And then once the connection is established for the data to be sent to a PHP script on a server?

**Edit:**

Thanks for all your answers! I have looked into local storage but this doesnt work as the user may revist the page but they still probably wont have an internet connection, so I was wondering if there is any type of script that can run locally all the time until there is an established internet connection

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) ? Did you really have searched around ? I got [this](http://www.devcurry.com/2014/01/using-localstorage-in-html5-with.html) ...

Comment: Do you mean **revisit** the site? As in **reload**? Does the Solution have to work if the browser (or even the tab) is closed and then the site is revisited?

Comment: Basically the data that has been collected and has been stored locally will need to be sent automatically if possible, without the page having to be reloaded by the user at anypoint

Comment: @KM123 That does not answer my Question: Should your Solution work even if teh browser window/tab is closed or reloaded? That is the important Question.

Comment: @AndreschSerj Ideally yes - Even if the browser window/tab is closed it should still be waiting to send the data to the server

Comment: @KM123 then i am affraid my solution would not work for you. However you could store the data in a cookie to retrieve it when the user revisits the page whilist being connected to the internet. Still, there is no software that does actively do anything while it is closed ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51352/discussion-between-km123-and-andresch-serj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - provided that they open your page again with an internet connection at a later date.

The steps are:-

1. Try and send message *(AJAX etc.*)
2. If it fails due to no connection - store to localstorage.
3. Have a loop that checks for *messages* in local storage.
4. If message found try to re-send.
5. Once message is sent remove it from local storage. (*AJAX `success`*)

Comment: the answer is no to this as a web page - they would have to be on your page and connected to the internet at some point to send a message - failing that browser plug-ins are your only real option.

Comment: Well you have inspired me to a solution I think! - So Thank you very much for your input and hopefully the solution which you have suggested will work :) - Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - you might also wnat to think about notifying the user when they are on your page without a connection that they have unsent messages - this may prompt them to find a connection or find an alternative means of sending the message - good luck and glad to see `appcache` is being used more and more!

Answer (score 2):

You can not run a script unless the page is opened.

The only way around this would be to create a Chrome Extention or FireFox Addon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome_Extensions

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on_(Mozilla)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Add-on_%28Mozilla%29)

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed possible if the website stays open.

You can have a javascript loop that checks some recource (*i.e. a tiny json file on your server*) and if it can read this successfully, it attempts to send the email/data.

If it is not, it waits for a certain time using [`timeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

You'll surely be able to find examples of this on the internet since this is often used in modern web development due to the often unstable connection of smartphones.

Answer (score 1):

you can try local storage to store the data and retrieve it after the browser re-opens Or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

If you use mozilla you can hack the XUL codes and inject your scripts into it. Otherwise you must hack the browser template which supports js